# Switch-Statement over multiple files (e.g. Plugin-System for switch-case-statements)

Tags: php, plugins, switch-statement

I want to create something like a plugin-system for dynamic switch statements like in the following example:

```
$command = $_POST['cmd'];
switch ($command) {

 include "./Ajax_Includer.php";

}
```

The File "Ajax_Includer" should now load all files in a specific folder. These files all contain one case-statement.

The advantage of this should be that I can add as many case-statements as my fingers can. And also the removal of the case statements would be easier by just killing or ignoring the file with the specific case-statement.

But I get an Error that I cannot use "Include" directly inside a switch. Does anyone know a workaround or is this not possible?

Comment: Why not use `if`s? `switch` would anyways silently mess it all up if you forget a single `break;`.

Comment: can't see why you couldn't include files in an switch/case. look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594504/switching-to-a-different-php-include - RTM too http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: but if I use `if`s then it could end up in performance loss due to `if...if...if`

Comment: ^ oh... well not enough code in your question. ask the guy below and/or see my links on how to do this with POST.

Comment: If you include(), you do file handling, and at that point the performance of a few ifs is not the question anymore.

Comment: @syck and the chance of hitting multiple `ifs` is higher. I dont want to implement a file-checker :D

Answer (score 1):

Break it like:

```
switch ($command) {
    case 'your_first_case':
        $file = "./Ajax_Includer.php";
        break;

    default:
        $file = null;
        break;
}
if($file){
    include $file
}
```

Although including files in `switch` is perfectly valid.

---

Update: If you want your 'case's in the included file, you'll get yourself  a parse error, as `switch()` is

> expecting case (T_CASE) or default (T_DEFAULT) or '}'

Comment: yeah but I dont want to include file into the case-statements. I want to include THE case-statements ;)

Comment: @Snickbrack, *that* is a design flaw. Perhaps consider breaking each case into a different file.

Comment: that is exactly what my question is about and if it is possible to do it like this

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of any 'hacks' to overcome this. Even tried it with an `eval` but no luck...

Comment: If I get you correctly, so you want to have a switch with only a default case in which you include the file? What would you gain with that? An alternative would be to add the `switch` inside your included file and directly(top-level) include the file.